# download multiple files from browser

Tags: java, flash, browser, download

How do I download multiple files at once from a browser without combining them into single file? I found all kinds of multiple file uploaders, but downloaders are missing. There is only JUpload, but it's old and became buggy recently. I believe both Java and Flash can do this: select a folder at client's HD and download everything there.

Comment: Don't get it. "without combining them into single file". Explain. Why is this bad?

Comment: So that user won't need to unarchive it.

Comment: Sure. That could be a reason. But it sounds strange. I feel that if I download a file I would not accidently download 100 files. That would really surprise me. I am not much of a programmer. But. If f.e. php can do it they you could translate that code into java? no?. Don't know what you want actually but that's how things often are here.

Comment: Java and Flash do it at client side (like embedded download manager). Server side provides each file by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think about is a performing multiple AJAX calls to each file separately. All this calls may be invoked by single click of user. This will look OK in Chrome because it does not ask (by default) where to put the downloaded file and put all files into pre-configured download directory.

I think that in Firefox the user will see pop-up that asks what to do with file (download or open) for each file separately.

MSIE will ask where to save each file.

Bottom line: this solution will look good in Chrome only. Other browsers should be configured properly.

Comment: Java definitely can do it, I think Flash should be able as well